# System/Protocol for sending data that deals with loss connection

Tags: streaming, real-time

This is not very much a coding question, but we are currently working at my company on a tool for processing data. This works this way :

- Local computer captures data from sensors every second and send it to cloud influxdb (time series-based database) on the fly
- Cloud computer retrieves data from cloud influxdb and preprocess it
- ... (this part is not important here)

The problem is that the internet connection on the local computer is instable. We the current infrastructure, we loose the data when the connection drops (which is very inconvenient for us). We would like to never loose the data even when the connection drops while keeping the real-time streaming data sent to influxdb (we could store data on disk locally beforehand and then sending it to influxdb but we loose the real time here)

We wanted to use Kafka or MQTM for this purpose but it does not seem to have good capabilities of handling connection loss (AFAIK)

Is there a protocol/system which can handle this problem ?

EDIT : we do not need high throughput as we have only 1 data per second

Comment: Maybe try RabbitMQ

Comment: I searched for it and it can be good. But I did not find how it reacts when message cannot be published. I've read about publishers confirms and so on but I did not find any mention about storing data on disk locally when message cannot be sent

Comment: Maybe use RabbitMQ as client local cache, client send data to local RabbitMQ, then another app or service get data from local RabbitMQ, and send to remote RabbitMQ. If confirm remore RabbitMQ receive data, then remove date from local RabbitMQ. or Maybe some solution or config can auto routing local RabbitMQ queue message to remote RabbitMQ queue.